# Transform Year-to-date to Quarterly data with data.table

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr

Quarterly data from a data provider has the issue that for some variables the quarterly data values are actually Year-to-date figures. That means the values are the sum of all previous quarters (Q2 = Q1 + Q2 , Q3 = Q1 + Q2 + Q3, ...). 
The structure of the original data looks the following:

```
 library(data.table)
 library(plyr)
 dt.quarter.test <- structure(list(Year = c(2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 2001L)
 , Quarter = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L)
 , Data.Year.to.Date = c(162, 405, 610, 938, 331, 1467, 1981, 2501))
 , .Names = c("Year", "Quarter", "Data.Year.to.Date"), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

In order to calculate the quarterly values I therefore need to subtract the previous Quarter from Q2, Q3 and Q4.
I've managed to get the desired results by using the `ddply` function from the `plyr` package.

```
dt.quarter.result <- ddply(dt.quarter.test, "Year"
  , transform
  , Data.Quarterly = Data.Year.to.Date  - shift(Data.Year.to.Date, n = 1L, type = "lag", fill = 0))

dt.quarter.result
  Year Quarter Data.Year.to.Date Data.Quarterly
1 2000       1               162            162
2 2000       2               405            243
3 2000       3               610            205
4 2000       4               938            328
5 2001       1               331            331
6 2001       2              1467           1136
7 2001       3              1981            514
8 2001       4              2501            520
```

But I am not really happy with the command, since it seems quite clumsy and I would like to get some input on how to improve it and especially do it directly within the data.table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the `data.table` syntax, and you might find [data.table cheat sheet](https://s3.amazonaws.com/assets.datacamp.com/img/blog/data+table+cheat+sheet.pdf) helpful:

```
library(data.table)
dt.quarter.test[, Data.Quarterly := Data.Year.to.Date - shift(Data.Year.to.Date, fill = 0), Year][]    

#    Year Quarter Data.Year.to.Date Data.Quarterly
# 1: 2000       1               162            162
# 2: 2000       2               405            243
# 3: 2000       3               610            205
# 4: 2000       4               938            328
# 5: 2001       1               331            331
# 6: 2001       2              1467           1136
# 7: 2001       3              1981            514
# 8: 2001       4              2501            520
```

Comment: Thanks, that looks a lot nicer. Was the first time I used the shift() function. Always amazing, how easy the solution sometimes is, when you get used to the available options.